# Delete rows from Azure Sql table using Azure Databricks with Pyspark

Tags: pyspark, azure-sql-database, azure-databricks

Below is the snippet which I am using

```
azuresqlOptions={ "driver":jdbcDriver, "url":jdbcUrl, "user":username, "port":jdbcPort, "password":password }

query = "(DELETE cone.address WHERE Address_ID=756 ) ad1" df1 = spark.read.format("jdbc").option("header","true").options(**azuresqlOptions).option("dbtable",query).load() display(df1)
```

I am getting below error:

```
 com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: A nested INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, or MERGE statement must have an OUTPUT clause.
```

Can any one help me on this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When deleting rows from SQL table in Azure data bricks with sample data

[image]

with below code:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession          
spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()    
Host = "<serverName>.database.windows.net"    
Port = 1433    
Database = "<dbName>"    
Username = "<userName>"    
Password = "<password>"    
Driver = "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"    
table = "<table>"    
Url = f"jdbc:sqlserver://{Host}:{Port};databaseName={Database}"

connectionProperties = {    
   "user": Username,    
    "password": Password,   
    "driver": Driver
}

query = f"(Delete {table} where Id = 1) AS subquery"
df = spark.read.jdbc(url=Url, table=query, properties=connectionProperties)
df.show()
```

I got the same error:

[image]

I tried below procedure to delete row from table. I have used filter function to delete row:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
df2 = df.filter(col("<condition>") 
df2.show()
```

[image]

I write the data frame into Sql table using below code:

```
df2.write.format("jdbc").mode("overwrite").option("url", "<Url>").option("dbtable", ""<table>").option("user", "<Username>").option("password", "<Password>").save()
```

The table updated successfully.

[image]

**Updated:**

You can use below code to execute delete query:

```
import pyodbc
conn = pyodbc.connect( 'DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};'
                       'SERVER=<serverNmae>.database.windows.net;'
                       'DATABASE=<db>;UID=<userName>;'
                       'PWD=<password>')
conn.execute('DELETE <tableName> WHERE <condition>')
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, My requirement is to execute the delete query in Azure SQL.

Comment: @Pradeep, I have updated the solution kindly check it.

Comment: Thank you Bhavani, we are looking alternative to pyodbc library. If you have any idea can you let us know.

Comment: as I see in couple of links pyodbc is not the suggestable library , any idea on this

Comment: If you are using Azure SQL Database, the pyodbc library is a suggested library for connecting to the database.

Comment: Yeah As of now we are using pyodbc. Thank you for the quick response